# window.location.href and hash are not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, coffeescript

```
previewOpen:->
 window.location.href="#/preview"
 window.setTimeout(@openView(@uuid),500)

openView:(uuid) ->
 $("#design_parts").empty();
 console.log("done emptying...");
 console.log(uuid)
 view= new Embellishment.Views.DP.Preview({uid:uuid} )
 $('#design_parts').html(view.render().el)
```

I am using coffee script, when I am trying hit the url, it is not getting redirected to that particular url and the next steps are getting executed later it is hitting that url. 
I am getting this issue only in chrome but it is working fine in firefox.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What URL are you trying to send the window to? `example.com/preview` or something else?

Comment: Can you try without "#" - window.location.href="/preview"

Comment: I am just appending it to the present url...so that it goes to the router

Comment: it is not working even after removing "#" pavi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout takes either a function or a string as its first parameter. You aren't giving it a function, you're invoking a function. So whatever `openView()` returns (likely `undefined`) is what is getting sent to setTimeout.

Try:

```
setTimeout =>
    @openView(@uuid)
, 500
```